# How can I display the Discount Value onSale of Products

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce

I am trying to display the Discount Value (%) of Products with the onSale Tag. What works for now is to display only the Products which are onSale. But I can't figure out which value stores the Discount Value.

```
{% set products = craft.commerce.products.find() %} {% for product in products %}
<li class="list-item">
    {% if product.defaultVariant.onSale == true %}
    <div class="pin circle">
        <h6>Sale!</h6>
        <h6 class="percent">{{ amount.saleAmount }}/h6>
        <h6>off</h6>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this myself, but I see two ways to get the percentage:

Take the `product.defaultVariant.saleAmount` and use maths in twig to work out the percentage - that should definitely work.  Twig math is a good general solution if you can't get the numbers you need directly from Commerce. See:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#math

However, I think you can use

```
 {% set sales = craft.commerce.getSales() %}
```

...to get all your SalesModels.

(see `/craft/plugins/commerce/models/Commerce_SaleModel.php`) as this model is not really documented yet it seems.

You'd loop through those and get the particular sale you're after (e.g. by `id`).  Then, it appears there is code in there to  `getDiscountAmountAsPercent` to get what you're after....however while `DiscountModel` has an attribute of `percentDiscount` on it, SaleModel does not appear to so I don't *think* you can get at it directly in your templates currently.

Unfortunately I am a bit pushed for time in terms of actually trying it to see.  But Twig maths will do it for sure if you get stuck with a more direct approach!

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try to figure it out tomorrow, i actually just need the value that the costumer enters to display something like a sticker on the product image to say how much % is off ..maybe there is a workaround if  the costumer just names the deal 20 for 20% and i can read out the deal name i.e.

Comment: will try to work it out and report here, thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the above answers aren't working for me, so I've done it the mathematical way...

Formula: ((newprice-oldprice)/oldprice)*100

In craft/twig code:

```
{% if product.defaultVariant.onSale %}
  <span class="badge">
    {% set procent = ((product.defaultVariant.salePrice-product.defaultPrice)/product.defaultPrice)*100 %}
    {{procent}}%
  </span>
{% endif %}
```

Hope it helps for those who where struggling also... :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [saleAmount](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/line-item-model#saleamount) is what you're looking for.

```
{% set amount = product.defaultVariant.saleAmount %}
```

Comment: i checked the docs again, i think you are right, i figured its saleAmount or discount but i cant cant it working, i want do output the value i entered in the dashboard (i.e. 20%) i updated the code above.