# Is there a way to print the tax and discount percentages?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is there a way to get the tax and discount percentage when applicable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer here for discount percentages:
[How can I display the Discount Value onSale of Products](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17471/how-can-i-display-the-discount-value-onsale-of-products)

For tax, I think there answer is actually currently the same, I don't *think* you can currently retrieve tax rates in templates as such (you can get tax categories models, but not, it seems, the rate models.  So again, twig maths might be your best bet here.